# LinkButton no ejecuta evento onclick

Tags: asp.net

Tengo un linkButton el cual debe ejecutar un evento onclick y abrir una ventana modal, el problema es que no ejecuta el onclick pero si abre el modal, aqui mi codigo del linkbutton

```html
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="reporte" CausesValidation="false" type="button" 
onclick="reporte_Click" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Report" class="btn btn-success"> 
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Puede que estes llamando mal tu Archivo JS en tu enlace Script de tu documento HTML y te recomiendo usar OnClientClick que es el mas indicado cuando estas usando ASP.NET.

Comment: Hola, no utilizo js para esto, el evento onclick="reporte_Click" ejecuta codigo c# mientras que data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Report"  es para abrir el modal bootstrap y este si funciona bien, lo que no ejecuta es el codigo behind c#

Comment: ya probaste añadiendolo return a tu onclick. onclick="return reporte_Click"

Comment: me marca un Error de compilación en el navegador

Answer (score 0):

Cree el control Link button dinamicamente. No me manda llamar el método que utilizó para ese botón. ¿Cómo le puedo hacer?

Así lo creo:

LinkButton linkButton = new LinkButton();
linkButton.Click += new EventHandler(selected_Click);

Este es el método:

```
protected void selected_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Aquí no tengo nada
}
```

*Le puse un punto de interrupción para ver si entraba al método, pero nada.

Agradezco de antemano su ayuda.